# declaring a variable not on the page yet error

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have this code at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$window = $(window),
$sidebar = $(".sidebar"),
sidebarTop = $sidebar.position().top,
sidebarHeight = $sidebar.height(),
$footer = $(".footer"),
footerTop = $footer.position().top,    
$sidebar.addClass('fixed');

$window.scroll(function(event) {
    scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
    topPosition = Math.max(0, sidebarTop - scrollTop),
    topPosition = Math.min(topPosition, (footerTop - scrollTop) - sidebarHeight);
    $sidebar.css('top', topPosition);
});
});
```

This is producing an **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null**

I'm still new to jQuery but I'm guessing this is because .sidebar isn't on the page yet, it's a div in an external html file that get injected via AJAX.

I'm thinking I need to change the $(document).ready(function(){ line so it grabs the variable when the .sidebar is actually on the page but I don't really know how to do this. 
I've been playing around with the .on() method but no luck yet.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thank you!

## **EDIT:**

So with this updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        var $sidebar = $('.sidebar'),
            sidebarTop = $sidebar.position().top,
            sidebarHeight = $sidebar.height(),
            $footer = $('#footer'),
            footerTop = $footer.position().top,    
            $sidebar.addClass("fixed");

        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        topPosition = Math.max(0, sidebarTop - scrollTop),
        topPosition = Math.min(topPosition, (footerTop - scrollTop) - sidebarHeight);
        $sidebar.css('top', topPosition);
});
});
```

I now get an **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier** under the $sidebar.addClass("fixed"); line.

This means that $sidebar is declared? BUT IT IS!? Right?

Any help guys, this is driving me nuts!

## **EDIT 2:**

So updated code again, was getting an error with the window var not defined so made that global:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function(event) {
    var $sidebar = $(".sidebar"),
        sidebarTop = $sidebar.position().top,
        sidebarHeight = $sidebar.height(),
        $footer = $("#footer"),
        footerTop = $footer.position().top;    

    $sidebar.addClass('fixed');
    scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
    topPosition = Math.max(0, sidebarTop - scrollTop),
    topPosition = Math.min(topPosition, (footerTop - scrollTop) - sidebarHeight);
    $sidebar.css('top', topPosition);
});

});
```

BUT now .sidebar has a constant **style="top: -370px;** attached to it.

Anyone? Haha... AH!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should declare your variables with the `var` keyword otherwise they'll be added to the global scope.

Second, if you put the `$sidebar` selector and all the other variables within your scroll function then it will make the selection upon scroll instead of only once at document load.  So if the sidebar is available at the point when the user scrolls everything should behave correctly.

Essentially, it should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $window.scroll(function(event) {
        var $window = $(window),
            $sidebar = $(".sidebar"),
            sidebarTop = $sidebar.position().top,
            sidebarHeight = $sidebar.height(),
            $footer = $(".footer"),
            footerTop = $footer.position().top;    

        $sidebar.addClass('fixed');
        scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
        topPosition = Math.max(0, sidebarTop - scrollTop),
        topPosition = Math.min(topPosition, (footerTop - scrollTop) - sidebarHeight);
        $sidebar.css('top', topPosition);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much!
However, now I get a Unexpected Identifier error at this line:
 $sidebar.addClass('fixed');